# Cannot load 'paperclip/storage/ftp' when using paperclipftp in Rails 3

Tags: ruby, paperclip

I've just installed paperclip 2.3.3 and paperclipftp 0.1.0.

Paperclip was working fine, the attachments were saving and everything was great.

Enter paperclipftp.

I've included both gems in my Gemfile, installed it with bundle and made sure all dependencies were satisfied. I've also double checked that all my ftp info is correct and the server is working fine.

When I try to attach a file using ftp:

```
has_attached_file :photo, 
    :styles => { 
        :small => "204x159#", 
        :original => "460X370#"
    },
    :storage => :ftp,
    :path => "/:attachment/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
    :url => "http://kickassserver.com/_myfolder/:attachment/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename"
```

I get the following error:

```
Paperclip::StorageMethodNotFound in SetupsController#create

Cannot load 'paperclip/storage/ftp'
```

I'm thinking that paperclipftp isn't actually being loaded by my app. Is there a way I can check to see that it's actually being loaded, or has anyone else experienced this?

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: can you help me to know what is this ?http://kickassserver.com  it this your aplication path ? :url=>"http://kickassserver.com/_myfolder/:attachment/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename"

Answer (score 1):

I have ruby 1.9.2p180 and the problem is that the timeout class being loaded.

Only add,

```
require 'timeout'
```

to the application.rb and this will fix your error.